# jQuery Progress Bar with Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a progress bar that pops-up and shows you continuous progress as you fill out inputs, and it works well with all input type except radio buttons. This is because each input needs a "required" tag for it to register as progress, however this means I would have to put a required tag for each radio option, so instead of showing you answered the question by selecting one of the radio answers, you have to click on all of the radio buttons. I tried applying the "required" tag to a container holding both radio buttons but it doesn't work.

Here is my codepen so you can see exactly what I am working with.

http://codepen.io/er40/pen/ugdqa

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a more complicated work around with a required hidden input that changes value based on radios selected, but i think for what you are doing, conceptually, it makes more sense to have a single checkbox there with a value of "yes" because you want to make sure the user selects "yes" before continuing.

right now there are two radio buttons that i can select at the same time and still progress, which doesn't make a lot of sense.

**edit: the complicated workaround**

add a hidden, required input to the radio group:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="yes">YES
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="no">NO
<input type="hidden" class="radio_selected" required="required" />
```

and in your javascript, something along the lines of this to give the hidden input a value:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
  var radio_selected = $(this).next('.radio_selected');
  if (radio_selected.val() !== 'true') {
    radio_selected.val("true");
  }
});
```

then modify your plugin to detect that change.

this only really works because your radios can't be deselected.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up with the radio buttons. I just fixed it so you can only select one of the two radio options. http://codepen.io/er40/pen/ugdqa

Comment: added what I was referring to by "complicated solution" above. you'll have to rig it to work with your plugin, but it is changing the value of the hidden input when you click a radio.

Comment: if it ends up working out, would you be so kind as to mark this as solved?

Comment: were you having a hard time validating the hidden input?

Comment: No, its not the validation that I am having trouble with. Its just the progress bar filling up to 100%. 

Right now I have both radio buttons with the same name, type, and different values. I should be able to just have "required" on one of them and it will validate when you click on any. However, it only adds to the progress bar if you click the radio with "required" in it.